# How to align your datepicker be left according to your position?

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I need some help, i have datepicker on bootstrap and want to find a way to position it. According to be left and mine does not do that at help. Please help me to improve my logic below. Thanks and also want to find a way to make my datepicker be in South African format, 'yy-mm-dd'. Mine shows 'dd-mm-yy', e.g 11/24/2019 it does not make. Please assist, thanks.

```
  <div class = "container">
     <div align="left">
     <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
       <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" 
       placeholder="startdate" width="110"/>
       <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
       <input type="text" class= "input-sm form-control" 
       placeholder="enddate" width="110"/>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div><br>

      // date functionality
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
       dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
        "orientation":"left"
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap Html should be like this:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex">
            <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
                <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" 
                placeholder="startdate" width="110"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
                <input type="text" class= "input-sm form-control" 
                placeholder="enddate" width="110"/>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then it'll be left aligned.

And for dd-mm-yyyy format your script should be like this.

```
// date functionality
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
         dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
         "orientation":"left"
     });
});
```

I hope it'll help you

Comment: HTML code seem on my side, still works the same as before, or maybe my Iframe seem to hide this implementation for my datepicker to show orientation to be left. <iframe   width="650" height="250" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/899906/charts/8?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=1&type=line&update=15">
  </iframe><br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>